# Detect if computer was started using WOL or power switch

Tags: power-management, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to check if a computer was started using Wake on LAN or using the regular power switch under Linux?

Comment: I don't use WOL but it does require kernel/driver support, so the OS must know the difference and I'd bet my hat it gets logged (e.g. `dmesg`).